# mycliをmysql8.0で使おうとするとエラーが起きる

Tags: mysql

`mycli`でMySQLに接続しようとすると、ログイン時にエラーが起きます。
どなたか対処法わかる方いないでしょうか?

**エラー内容**

```
$ mycli -h localhost -u root
Password: 
(1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

**試したこと**
mysqlのコネクションタイプをTCPに変更

**実行環境**
OS : Mac OS X 10.13.6
mysql : 8.0.12 for osx10.13
mycli : 1.16.0

**my.cnfの内容**

```ini
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

[client]
protocol=tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using password: NO` はパスワード使わずにログインした場合に表示されます。
`mycli` の `-p` オプションを指定してみるとどうでしょうか？

```
$ mycli -h localhost -u root -p
Password: ←パスワードを入力
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。一旦mysqlを削除した後、今度は`xampp`の方で入れ直した所`mycli -h localhost -u root -p "自分のパスワード"`を試した所無事ログインできました。

Comment: @ybn 解決したようで良かったです。ちなみに `-p "PASSWORD"` は 大事なパスワードが Shellの history に記録されてしまうので セキュリティ上 あんまり好ましくない作法となっておりますので ご留意くだされ。

Answer (score 0):

rootユーザの権限設定がされていないのではないですかね。エラーメッセージでググると、同じ解決策がたくさんでてきますよ。例えば、[このブログ](https://blog.kuromusubi.com/develop/language/mysql/20180730-access-denied-root)とか。